# Delay Send/Receive in Outlook with Exchange

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook-2010

When I get into work I don't really want to be distracted by incoming emails, at the sametime I don't want to close down Outlook.

With standard SMTP you can set a Send/Receive interval, is it possible to set a similar setting so that Outlook will only sync with Exchange every x Number of minutes?

I am using Outlook2010 and have not been able to find an answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Office 2010, the "Send/Receive Group" is under the "Send/Receive" TAB in the Ribbon.  Select "Send/Receive Groups", then click "Define Send/Receive Groups...", click "Edit" (the default should be all accounts), select the accounts you want to include in this group, and accept.

I added an Exchange server to my pre-configured POP3 Outlook 2010 client.  POP3 updated every 35 minutes but Exchange was immediate.  I applied the settings and all accounts send/receive every 35 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is set on the exchange server. The only thing you could do is the work offline and connect so now and then.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an option for it, it will be in the Send/Receive Groups settings.  In Outlook 2007 (sorry, I don't have access to 2010): Tools > Send/Receive > Send/Receive Settings > Define Send/Receive Groups.  From there you can define the send/receive interval or disable scheduled send/receives completely, in which case you can also define a key to press when you want to receive email.  Of course, since you're on Exchange, all bets are off because much of this is likely to be controlled by the server.  But you could ask the server admin to set up something specific to your user account.  There are also options that control what Outlook does when it receives new email, including sounds, desktop alerts, mouse pointer changes and system tray indicators, all of which can typically be disabled.  Again in Outlook 2007 (sorry!): Tools > Options > Preferences > E-mail options > Advanced e-mail options.

Answer (score 0):

See - http://www.msoutlook.info/question/300. It relates to outlook in cached mode syncing with exchange. requires registry changes at the client

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  One of the guidelines of the site is to include the relevant steps from the page rather than just the link.  This way, if the link goes down in the future, the answer will still be here.  Adding the registry key it mentions would be a way to turn this good answer into a great one!
http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer