# How to disable Outlook 2010 automatic send/receive?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I want to disable automatic send and receive of emails in Outlook 2010. The ideal world would be to have to click the send/receive button, but anything close to that would work.

I already tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/170859/delay-send-receive-in-outlook-with-exchange), but it didn't work.

UPDATE: I'm using Microsoft Exchange.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Exchange or POP3/IMAP?

Comment: Also, are you trying to limt both sending and receiving, or just one? If one, which one?

Comment: @KCotreau: I'm using MS Exchange, and I have *two* inboxes. I prefer to limit just receiving, but if it isn't possible, I can limit both.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure you can limit it to one. Why do you have two mail boxes, if I may ask. The reason I ask is that if it is just about multiple e-mail addresses, and not segregation of mail, you can associate both e-mail addresses with one Exchange mailbox. I have 20+ e-mail addresses associated with my account: dell@, microsoft@, etc. for each company I do business with. If they ever allow the address to get polluted by SPAM, I can delete it without killing my main address, AND I know who was careless with my e-mail address.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried going to Send/Receive>Send/Receive Groups>Disable Scheduled Send/Receive?

[image]

As a note, you can also add the Send/Receive button to the Quick Access Toolbar as you can see the little icon near the top left in screenshot 1.

[image]

Comment: This does not work when connected to an Exchange account.

Answer (score 5):

**Step 1:** Open Outlook and go to Tools –> Options.

[image: disable_automatic_sending_message_outlook]

**Step 2:** Click on the Mail Setup tab, if you want to disable automatic sending of messages, just uncheck the box next to “Send Immediately when connected”, this will disable automatic sending of messages.

[image: disable_automatic_send_receive_outlook]

**Step 3:** Click on the Send/Receive button in the same tab, this will open a new options window. To disable automatic send/receive for your account group, just select the group from the list and uncheck the box next to “Schedule an automatic send/receive every”.

With the automatic send/receive disable you will still have to download emails, just press the F9 key with the Outlook window in focus, whenever you want to manually send/receive email in Outlook.

Comment: Any reason why this wouldn't work?

Comment: With Exchange, disabling Send works, but disabling Scheduled And & Receive doesn't disable messages from being received.

Comment: As the question was updated after my answer, maybe you should think of deleting negative score?

Answer (score 1):

None of the above will work for Microsoft Outlook 2010.  The actual way to stop automatic receiving of emails is to go to the 'send/receive' tab.  Click 'Work Offline.'

When you are ready to receive emails, simply click the 'Work Offline' button again.  It should automatically update folders.  If it doesn't and you are connected to the Internet then hit 'Send/Receive All Folders'.

Answer (score 0):

With OUTLOOK 2010 - to disable automatic send when connected, do the following steps:

> Select **File** --> Select **Options** --> Select **Advanced** --> With the **'Send and receive'** section --> Untick the '**Send immediately when connected**' box --> then press 'OK' button.

Comment: Up, because it worked perfectly. However, Outlook keeps receiving automatically.

Comment: ACTUALLY:
Select File --> Select Options --> Select Advanced --> With the 'Send and receive' section --> Untick the 'Send immediately when connected' box --> then press 'OK' button. Then also click the adjacent send/receive button and uncheck the "automatically send/receive every ( ) minutes.