# Outlook suddenly sends messages without them going to the Outbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

After composing an outgoing message in Outlook 2010, I used to click on *Send* and it went to my Outbox for me to check before clicking on Send/Receive.

Suddenly the process has changed and the message is being sent without going into the Outbox.

How do I reset the options to send the message to the Outbox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable Outlook 2010 automatic send/receive?](http://superuser.com/questions/310082/how-to-disable-outlook-2010-automatic-send-receive)

Comment: nope, sounds to me like a different issue.